# Behavior change of gzip Reader in golang 1.7.3 (compared to 1.6.3)

Tags: go

I have a program that reads gzip compressed json packets from a network connection. The sender does not close the connection after sending the gzip packet. In `go1.6.3` this works perfectly, i.e., the gzip packet is decoded after the gzip end-sequence is received, but in `go1.7.3` the reader blocks as there is no `io.EOF`.

Here is a sample that simulates the network connection using a pipe (note that the writer stays open to simulate the open connection):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "compress/gzip"
    "io"
    "runtime"
)

type TestJSON struct {
  TestString string `json:"test"`
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Version: %s\n", runtime.Version())
    pipeReader, pipeWriter := io.Pipe();

    go writeTo(pipeWriter);
    readFrom(pipeReader);
}

func writeTo(pipeWriter *io.PipeWriter){
    // marshall and compress
    testJSON := TestJSON{TestString: "test",}

    jsonString, err := json.Marshal(testJSON)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("Marshalling Error: %s\n", err)
      return
    }

    gzipOut := gzip.NewWriter(pipeWriter)
    _, err = gzipOut.Write(jsonString)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("Error Writing: %s\n", err)
      return
    }
    gzipOut.Close()
    //pipeWriter.Close()
}

func readFrom(pipeReader *io.PipeReader){
    // decompress and unmarshall
    gzipIn, err := gzip.NewReader(pipeReader)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("Error creating reader: %s\n", err)
      return
    }
    defer gzipIn.Close()

    jsonDecoder := json.NewDecoder(gzipIn)
    msg := new(TestJSON)
    err = jsonDecoder.Decode(msg)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("Error decoding: %s\n", err)
      return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Recived: %v\n", msg)
}
```

Based on this situation I have 2 questions:

1. Which is the correct behavior?
2. If `go1.7.3` behaves correctly, how can I decode incoming gzip packets on an open network connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the correct behavior. The old behavior of the gzip.Reader was a side effect of it being able to return a final read without `io.EOF`, then `(0, io.EOF)` in a subsequent call. Now that it properly waits for `io.EOF`, it will block waiting for the next gzip header or `io.EOF`.

If you don't expect more files, and you want to have the gzip trailer indicate the end of the file regardless of `io.EOF`, you have to set [`Reader.Multistream(false)`](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/#Reader.Multistream).

Your example works with that addition:

```
func readFrom(pipeReader *io.PipeReader) {
    // decompress and unmarshall
    gzipIn, err := gzip.NewReader(pipeReader)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating reader: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    gzipIn.Multistream(false)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BdaulxMza0